# Link print setting to a PDF document

Tags: pdf, printing

I have a PDF document and I want to know if there is a way that I can embed print setting into it - such as Page sizing to Actual size and print on both sides.

So when people print the PDF they don't need to change the print settings manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts of this can be done with the "Viewer Preferences" dictionary (see PDF 1.7 specification section 12.2 for details):

- PrintArea
- PrintClip
- PrintScaling
- Duplex
- PickTrayByPDFSize
- PrintPageRange
- NumCopies

However, as usual this depends on the PDF viewer actually using these options. So you might wanna try this out with the PDF viewers your clients use.